# Monopoly cheaters edition

Tags: monopoly, monopoly-cheaters-edition

So basically I was playing it with my boyfriend and his mum. I was doing property swap cheat and I took his park lane and swapped it for old Kent road but before someone else rolled I landed on park lane. I didn’t know wether to pay the money for the rent or say I had the card so I said I had the card. My boyfriend said that I got caught and had to give the card back because I got caught but I don’t think I did. There’s no rule about wether you pay or don’t pay and say you have it so I didn’t know what to do and he says I was wrong but I admitted before he caught me plus what else was I supposed to do. My boyfriends mum agreed with me

Answer (score 1):

As long as someone called out "Cheat", and explained what you did, you were caught.

This is covered on the first page of the rules:

> When you’re ready to cheat:
>
> 1. Secretly do what’s on the Cheat card. Then you must wait until the next player rolls the dice. If no one catches you before then, you got away with the cheat!
> 2. After the next player rolls the dice, let everyone know that you cheated, and how.
> 3. Collect the reward described on the back of the card.
> 4. Return the card to the bottom of the Cheat deck, and place a new one face up on the board.
>
> **How do I catch a cheater?**
> When you think that someone’s cheated, call out, ‘CHEAT!’, and explain how they cheated before the next player rolls the dice.
> If the accused cheat is guilty, they must take the penalty on the back of the Cheat card.
> Then return the card to the bottom of the Cheat deck, and place a new one face up on the board.

There is potentially one saving grace here, which is this bit:

> If you can’t prove that you’re innocent, the other players must decide if you cheated, and who deserves a penalty.

So, in the case of a dispute who receives the penalty is up to the other players.

Comment: I don’t think the saving grace helps here. That’s part of the section about being falsely accused, and she wasn’t falsely accused in this case.

Comment: @GendoIkari, it certainly doesn't help if she was being honest, but it is the cheaters edition.

Comment: Well he didn’t notice but I had landed on park lane and he said to give his rent but I didn’t know wether to pay or tell him I had to I told him I had it. He didn’t catch me cheating I admitted to cheating cause I didn’t know what to do

Comment: The rules make no mention of how the person needs to find out you cheated, only that they need to find out before the next turn. Whatever circumstances led to it, the only point that really matters is that he called you out on cheating before the next turn.

Comment: Well he didn’t call me out

Comment: If he did not call out, ‘CHEAT!’ as the rules describe, then he did not follow the rules as written, and you technically were not caught. However, as with many "Family" games, the rules are a little loose, and one could reasonably expect that if a cheat became obvious the formalities could be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

KMR’s answer looks correct. I will add that your mistake was announcing that you had the card. It’s not your job to make sure you pay rent, it’s up to the person who is owed money to ask for it. You could have just not said anything and hoped that the next person continued on.

If the owner did notice that you landed on Park Lane and asked you for the rent; you could have just given them the rent and not said anything. You can’t argue that you don’t owe rent because you took the deed when your goal is to not let anyone find out that you took the deed. You haven’t successfully completed the cheat until your turn is over. The rules aren’t clear on who the legitimate owner of Park Lane was for the remainder of your turn.

Comment: Well he didn’t notice but I had landed on park lane and he said to give his rent but I didn’t know wether to pay or tell him I had to I told him I had it. He didn’t catch me cheating I admitted to cheating cause I didn’t know what to do. I had already done the cheat before my go